# flask application giving 504 timeout through Uwsgi and Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, keras, uwsgi

i am trying to deploy my keras model. it works fine with flask on port `5000` and when i try to test serving it through Uwsgi by this command `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app`, it gives me the desired result. the problem arises when i try to configure a separate Uwsgi fie and then an Nginx configuration to make the deployment for longer run so that it can be served through multiple ports through nginx. it gives me a **504 timeout error** when i run this url

`http://35.230.90.108/predict/ethnicity?auth_token=WyIxYSDFg467YT.A3MmJlODcyODkzOGQzZjk4YzUiXQ.B5e5SgsDcaMgiRqx21Ydf8M&url=https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/768073/110309945/stock-photo-portrait-of-smiling-young-black-man-in-the-interior-of-coffee-shop-110309945.jpg`.

i am using this tutorial for deployment:

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04
```

Here are the codes for deployment file, nginx configuration and Uwsgi configuration.

**deployment file**

```
import dlib
import requests
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

auth_token = 'WyIxYSDFg467YT.A3MmJlODcyODkzOGQzZjk4YzUiXQ.B5e5SgsDcaMgiRqx21Ydf8M'

top_model_weights_ethnicity = 'ethnicity.071217.23-0.28.hdf5'
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
confidence_ethnicity = '0.59'

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
graph = K.get_session().graph

class_to_label_ethnicity = {"0": "arabs", "1": "asia", "2": "black", "3": "hispanics-latinos",
                            "4": "southasia", "5": "white"}

def get_face(path):
    with graph.as_default():
        img = io.imread(path)
        dets = detector(img, 1)
        output = None
        for i, d in enumerate(dets):
            img = img[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right()]
            img = resize(img, (img_width, img_height))
            output = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            break
        return output


def get_pretrained_model():
    with graph.as_default():
        pretrained_model = applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                                                          input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
        return pretrained_model


def get_features(image, pretrained_model):
    with graph.as_default():
        features = pretrained_model.predict(image)
        return features


with graph.as_default():
    pretrained_model = get_pretrained_model()
    model_ethnicity = Sequential()
    model_ethnicity.add(Flatten(input_shape=(3, 3, 1536)))
    model_ethnicity.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model_ethnicity.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model_ethnicity.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    model_ethnicity.load_weights(top_model_weights_ethnicity)

@app.route("/predict/ethnicity", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_ethnicity():
    with graph.as_default():
        if request.args.get('auth_token') != auth_token:
            abort(make_response(jsonify(message="No valid access token. Write an email to research@influencerdb.com "
                                                "to become authenticated."), 403))
        confidence = request.args.get('confidence', confidence_ethnicity)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                abort(make_response(jsonify(message="No image found. Use 'file' as a key to upload an image."), 404))
            else:
                file = request.files['file']
                path_to_img = "uploaded/%s" % file.filename
                file.save(path_to_img)
        else:
            path_to_img = request.args.get('url')
        if get_face(path_to_img) is None:
            abort(make_response(jsonify(message="No face found."), 454))
        else:
            features = get_features(get_face(path_to_img), pretrained_model)
            prediction = model_ethnicity.predict_proba(features)
            ethnicity = {class_to_label_ethnicity[str(y)]: str(value) for (x, y), value in np.ndenumerate(prediction)}
            suggestion = class_to_label_ethnicity[str(np.argmax(prediction[0]))] \
                if np.max(prediction[0]) > float(confidence) else ""
            return jsonify({'probabilities': ethnicity, 'suggestion': suggestion}), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**myproject.ini (wsgi configuration)**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5
socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

**systemd unit file**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target
[Service]
User=rehan_aziz
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/rehan_aziz/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/rehan_aziz/anaconda3/envs/myproject/bin"
ExecStart=/home/rehan_aziz/anaconda3/envs/myproject/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**nginx config file**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 35.230.90.108;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/rehan_aziz/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

**wsgi app serving file**

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: what is the name of your deployment file?

Comment: @ManishMahendru it's name is also `myproject`

Comment: If it is "myproject.py" then make it "wsgi.py" because in "myproject.ini" you have mentioned the module as wsgi : app. Hope it works for you

Comment: @ManishMahendru i have a seperate file for that purpose which i just added which is importing the app and running the file. and that file name is `wsgi.py`. similar  to module name. i think i am getting the timeout error because of inception model not being loaded from the internet within the living time of nginx (not sure though). i tried changing the timeouts but it didn't work

Comment: Any Solution fors this issue, I am getting the same thing here !

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is a problem with Keras and threading in uwsgi

so setting master to false and change processes to 1 fix it for me, this is still a problem though as it doesn't scale. But well it works for experimentation

so change this setting in `myproject.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
master = false <-- this
processes = 1 <-- and this
socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

Comment: if it doesnt work, you might also want to add `cheaper = 0`

Comment: I am not sure about others but adding `lazy-apps = true` did the job for me. I did not need any other parameters.

Comment: Can confirm that the solution that Pramesh mentioned works well for me as well, with Tensorflow 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same timeout issue.I used `lazy-apps = true` in uwsgi config file.
My config as follows

```
[uwsgi]
module = main:app
master = true
processes = 2
threads = 1
enable-threads = true
need-app = true
lazy-apps = true
http = 127.0.0.1:4444
```